# React Table format null dates

Tags: react-table

I am using moment.js to format my dates in a react-table. Currently, if a date is null it displays 'Invalid Date', however, I would like to alter this default behavior and would prefer that the cell to remain blank if no date exists in the database. How can I do this?

CURRENT CONFIGURATION - this formats the date perfectly but lables null date values as 'Invalid date'and I don't want that :

```
     {
        id: "DATE_FIELD",
        Header: 'Date',
        accessor: d => {
            d.DATE_FIELD
            return Moment(d.DATE_FIELD)
                .local()
                .format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm")
        }
```

I've tried the following ternary statements but they didn't do anything:

```
accessor: d => {
        d.DATE_FIELD === 'Invalid date' ? "" :
            d.DATE_FIELD
            return Moment(d.DATE_FIELD)
                .local()
                .format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm")
        }
```

AND

```
 accessor: d => {
        d.DATE_FIELD === null ? "" :
            d.DATE_FIELD
            return Moment(d.DATE_FIELD)
                .local()
                .format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm")
        }
```

I also tried the code below but got an error `Unexpected token, expected :`

```
 accessor: d => { d.DATE_FIELD ? 
            d.DATE_FIELD
            return Moment(d.DATE_FIELD)
                .local()
                .format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm") : ""
        }
```